# Does weak convergence of processes imply adapted to filtration?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Supposed that $X_N$ are continuous stochastic processes all adapted to filtration $\mathcal F_t$. Suppose that $X_N$ converge weakly on the space of continuous functions to $X$. Then is $X$ adapted to $\mathcal F_t$?

We have that $\{X_N(t)\leq u\}\in \mathcal F_t$ for all $N$ but does this lead to $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $(\Omega^{2}, \mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{G}, P \otimes P)$ be a product of a non-trivial probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{G},P)$, and let $X$ and $Y$ be the projections: $X(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}) = \omega_{1}$, $Y(\omega_{1},\omega_{2}) = \omega_{2}$.
Setting $X_{N}(t) := X$ for $t \geq 0,N \geq 0$ and $\mathcal{F}_{t} := \sigma(X) \ (t \geq 0)$, the process $X_{N}$ is a $(\mathcal{F}_{t})$-adapted continuous process (actually, it is constant).
Since $X$ and $Y$ have a common distribution, $X_{N}$ converges in distribution to a constant process $Y(t) := Y \ (t \geq 0)$.
But obviously, $Y$ is not $\sigma(X)$-measurable (we easily see $\sigma(X) = \{ A \times \Omega \mid A \in \mathcal{G} \}$ and $\sigma(Y) = \{ \Omega \times A \mid A \in \mathcal{G} \}$), and thus, it is not $(\mathcal{F}_{t})$-adapted.